# If the order of $x\in G$ is $p$, the smallest prime dividing $|G|$, and $h^{-1}xh=x^{10}$ for some $h\in G$, then $p=3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a group and let $p$ be the smallest prime dividing $|G|$. Let $x\in G$ be such that $|x|=p$. If $\exists h\in G$ such that $h^{-1}xh=x^{10}$, then show that $p=3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this one till another way is appear here. This is my attempt. Since $|G|<\infty$ so we can speak about $|h|=m$. We know that: $$h^{-m}xh^m=x^{10^m}\longrightarrow x^{10^m-1}=e_G\longrightarrow p|10^m-1$$

Comment: I do not see how $h^{-m}xh^m = x^{10^m}$

Comment: @Ink: $(h^{-1}xh)^{10}=x^{10^2}\to(h^{-1}x^{10}h)=x^{10^2}$ but $h^{-1}xh=x^{10}$ so put it in the previous, we have $(h^{-1}(h^{-1}xh)h)=x^{10^2}\to \cdots$

Comment: Ok, I see it now.

Comment: $\Large\color{red}{\bf \heartsuit}^+$

Answer (score 5):

Let $\eta\colon \langle x\rangle\to\langle x\rangle, g\mapsto h^{-1}xh$ denote the automorphism of $\langle x\rangle$ given by conjugation with $h$. Since $\operatorname{Aut}(\langle x\rangle)$ has exactly $\phi(|x|)=p-1$ elements, we see that $|\eta|\le p-1$. Also, $|\eta|$ divides $|h|$, hence has no prime factors $\le p-1$. We conclude that $\eta$ is the identity, i.e. $x^{10}=x$ and hence $|x|$ divides $10-1=9$.

*Remark:* Obviously, the $10$ can be repaced by $28, 82, \ldots, 3^m+1$, or more generally by $q^m+1$ to conclude $p=q$ instead of $p=3$.